# Google analytics vs IP change

Tags: google-analytics

Is there a way to keep one's IP excluded from Google Analytics logs even when it occasionally changes ? I'm asking because even if I was informed that my IP changed I would still find boring to go each time in GA to update the IP.

Comment: Does the IP address change within a certain range? If it does, you can add the range to GA.

Comment: Haven't thought about that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is using a **blocking cookie**. You'll have to execute some js code from your domain and create a filter in analytics:

http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55481